# Trim or remove single white space char from delimited text

Tags: python

I have an issue where I am getting a # delimited file, however, in between the hashes, there is a single white space character signifying an empty value. This is causing me problems when I try to query the file later on. Is there a way I can remove all instances in a delimited line where just a single white space char exists?

Here's a sample line from my file.

```
40001#World Music#Mike Oldfield#Tubular Bells#   53# # #
```

I would want the string to be...

```
40001#World Music#Mike Oldfield#Tubular Bells#   53###
```

Comment: What about the "53" value, wouldn't you want that white space gone too?

40001#World Music#Mike Oldfield#Tubular Bells#53###

Wouldn't that be an easy replace of "# " with "#"? I may be overlooking something.

Comment: No, I don't actually want that value trimmed, I need to have context of the number of characters for that field - spaces and all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using ternary conditionals and list comprehensions, you can do:

```
s = "40001#World Music#Mike Oldfield#Tubular Bells#   53# # #"
s2 = "#".join([i if i != " " else "" for i in s.split("#")])
print s2
```

prints

```
40001#World Music#Mike Oldfield#Tubular Bells#   53###
```

No need for imports (e.g. RE)

Answer (score 0):

Use [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html).

```
import re

my_str = "40001#World Music#Mike Oldfield#Tubular Bells# 53# # #"
pattern = re.compile(r'(#)\s(#)\s(#)')

new_str = re.sub(pattern, r'\1\2\3', my_str)

print(new_str)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `re.sub` function.

```
re.sub(r'(?<=#) (?=#)', r'', string)
```

*OR*

```
re.sub(r'(?<=#)\s(?=#)', r'', string)
```

**Example:**

```
>>> s = "40001#World Music#Mike Oldfield#Tubular Bells#   53# # #"
>>> re.sub(r'(?<=#) (?=#)', r'', s)
'40001#World Music#Mike Oldfield#Tubular Bells#   53###'
```

- `(?<=#)` Positive lookbehind asserts that the match must be preceded by a `#`
- `\s` Matches a space character.
- `(?=#)` Positive lookahead which asserts that the match must be followed by a `#` character.

Comment: use `re.sub(r'(?<=#)\s+(?=#)', r'', string)` if you want to remove one or more inbetween spaces.

Answer (score 0):

This regex seems to do what you want, using a positive lookahead: http://regexr.com/3abqs

```
import re
str = "40001#World Music#Mike Oldfield#Tubular Bells#   53# # #"
strf = re.sub(r'#\s+(?=#)', r'#', str)
print(strf)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like:-

```
orig_str="40001#World Music#Mike Oldfield#Tubular Bells#   53# # #"
splitted_str = orig_str.split("#")[:-1]
new_str = ''
for item in splitted_str:
  if item.strip():
    new_str+=item
  new_str+="#"
print new_str
```

This would print `40001#World Music#Mike Oldfield#Tubular Bells#   53###`